# Type Error when i try to Render Objects out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, typeerror

i get the following error when i try to load questions(Array) for a quiz from a db.json server.

TypeError: this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion] is undefined

here is a sandbox of my project (relevant classes are play_quiz.js and db.json
https://codesandbox.io/s/kjllt?file=/quiz-project/server/db.json

the error occurs in line 79 of play_quiz.js

it worked just fine when i did it without the json server but not it seems to have some kind of problem recognising the content of the array. I hope someone can help me

Comment: The array is empty before the fetch finishes. so `this.state.questions[0]` returns undefined. See also: [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/996081) - Check that the length is greater than 0.

Comment: but this.state.questions.length gives 3 as a result, so the array cant be empty

Comment: If you add `console.log('Length: ' + this.state.questions.length)` in `render()`, what do you see?

Comment: i tried it with setting showscore to true so it prints {this.state.questions.length}.
the result was 3

Comment: Put the `console.log()` in the render. The fetch may be fast enough locally that you just don't notice the change.

Comment: it says from database lenght 3 but then it says 0.    

Length: 0 play_quiz.js:62    

Current state: play_quiz.js:15
From database: play_quiz.js:24
Array []
play_quiz.js:25
Length: 3 play_quiz.js:62
Length: 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227364/discussion-between-nikva-and-cbr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue is that when the component renders for the first time, `this.state.questions` is an empty array as set in the state's initial state.

Because of this, `this.state.questions[0]` returns undefined, until the API response finishes (which is started by `getRandomizedQuestions()` which is called by `componentDidMount` after the component has been *rendered* and mounted).

You need to handle this case. The way to solve it depends on how you want to solve it and what you want to show to the user while it's loading. Here's a few solutions:

#### 1. Just show "loading" until the array isn't empty.

```
render() {
  if (this.state.questions.length < 1) {
    return <div className="quiz-window">Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="quiz-window">
      // ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### 2. Use another ternary to show "loading" in the place of the block of JSX which depends on the array:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="quiz-window">
      {this.state.showScore ? (
        <div className="score-section">
          korrekt beantwortet: {this.state.score} von{" "}
          {this.state.questions.length}
        </div>
      ) : this.state.questions.length > 0 ? (
        <>
          <div className="question-section">
            <div className="question-count">
              <span>Frage {this.state.currentQuestion + 1}</span>/
              {this.state.questions.length}
            </div>
            <div className="question-text">
              {this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].title}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="answer-section">
            {this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].answers.map(
              (answer) => (
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answer.isCorrect)}
                >
                  {answer.title}
                </button>
              )
            )}
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if it's possible that the API returns an empty array and you want to handle that as a separate case:

#### 3. Introduce state variable that tracks when the data is loading and show loading until it's done

```
class Play_quiz extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentQuestion: 0,
    showScore: false,
    score: 0,
    questions: [],
    isLoading: true,
  };

  // ...

  getRandomizedQuestions = () => {
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3001/questions";
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log("From database:");
          console.log(result);

          let amountOfQuestions = result.length;
          let randomizedResult = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < amountOfQuestions; i++) {
            let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length);
            randomizedResult.push(result[randomIndex]);
            result.splice(randomIndex, 1);
          }

          this.setState({
            questions: randomizedResult,
            isLoading: false
          });
          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("An unexpected error occurred", error);
        }
      );
  };

  // ...

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <div className="quiz-window">Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="quiz-window">
        // ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See also: [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/996081)

Comment: wow, thanks for the effort with the detailed answer!  

unfortuinately there is still something not working in your solution number 2:  
TypeError: this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].answers.map is not a function

Comment: weirdly enough its working sometimes until the first question but if it works it only works until i click one answer and i get the TypeError: this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].answers.map is not a function

Comment: @nikva not all of your questions in `db.json` have an array as `answers` - some have a string.

Comment: yes, so i have to check if the question is multiple choice, if it isnt, then i have to completely redo how i load the questions?

Comment: Just change how you render them. The data loading aspect is already alright. If it's not an array (`Array.isArray()`), then don't `map` but render it somehow differently.

Comment: but i can still render the question text in the same way and after it i make two cases for the answer section

Comment: thanks for the help. Is it asked too much to provide the structure too? i was working on this the whole night and have to get up again in 4 hours

Comment: That sounds like an opportunity to ask another question which includes what you've already tried and what isn't working.

Comment: well, thanks anyways. you were a great help.